# I want to transform value in Yup but Formik is not returning the correct value

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, formik, yup

I have a value in a form (email) that I want to transform into lowercase. I have a transform in Yup that's working, but Formik does not show a lowercase value.

How do I make it so that, when I enter the email in uppercase, it gets converted to lowercase automatically?

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Formik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

import { DisplayFormikState } from "./helper";
import "./style.css";

const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  email: Yup.string()
    .transform(function (value, originalvalue) {
      return this.isType(value) && value !== null ? value.toLowerCase() : value;
    })
    .email()
    .required()
    .label("Email")
});

const App = () => (
  <div className="app">
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ name: "" }}
      onSubmit={() => {}}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
    >
      {(props) => {
        const { handleBlur, handleChange, values, errors, touched } = props;
        return (
          <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
            <h1>Email Form</h1>

            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              value={values.email}
            />
            {errors.email && touched.email && errors.email}

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>

            <DisplayFormikState {...props} />
          </form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Formik and Yup must have two separate duties:

- Formik manages the form's state (values)
- Yup performs validations and tells Formik whether the values are valid or not

Yup will not *set* the values in your form.

Remove the case conversion from the Yup transformation. Instead, simply set the value to lowercase and pass it to `setFieldValue()` before yup does the validation.

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  email: Yup.string()
    .email()
    .required()
    .label("Email")
});

const App = () => (
  <div className="app">
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ email: "" }}
      onSubmit={() => {}}
      validationSchema={validationSchema}
    >
      {(props) => {
        const { handleBlur, setFieldValue, values, errors, touched } = props;
        return (
          <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit}>
            <h1>Email Form</h1>

            <input
              type="email"
              name="email"
              onChange={(e)=>{
                const value = e.target.value || "";
                setFieldValue('email', value.toLowerCase());
              }}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              value={values.email}
            />
            {errors.email && touched.email && errors.email}

            <button type="submit">Submit</button>

            <DisplayFormikState {...props} />
          </form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-formik-yup-forked-gu1lnm?file=/src/App.js)