# Formik Input force lowercased

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a react Formik form that I want to stop users from entering Uppercased letters. I have a YUP check to ensure no uppercased are submitted but it would be helpful if uppercased letters were automatically converted to lowercased as the user types. How do I do this?

```
<Formik ...>
  <Form ...>
    <input .../>
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

Comment: Please provide a code example showing that you've attempted at solve this problem yourself.

Comment: @RoMilton - I've tried to use `onChange` unsuccessfully. Nothing has worked yet

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68722528/i-want-to-transform-value-in-yup-but-formik-is-not-returning-the-correct-value/68722791#68722791